# Vue3 - Setting up Pinia gives me an error of no active Pinia

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have this Vue app I would like to convert the store to a Pinia store because the normal reactive store just doesn't work and does not keep the values I set.

So I installed pinia and I have the following main.js file:

```
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import { store } from "./store";
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";

const pinia = createPinia();

const app = createApp(App).use(router, axios, store, pinia).mount("#app");
```

I have created a store inside a stores folder and here is that store:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useSomeAppStore = defineStore("someapp", () => {
    const userID = ref(0);
    const loggedIn = ref(false);
});
```

On the log in page I would like to use this store so I can save the user id in the store.

```
<script setup>
document.title = "Login | addapost";
import axios from "axios";
import { ref, watch, onBeforeMount, onMounted } from "vue";
import { useSomeAppStore } from "@/stores/someapp";
import { useRouter, useRoute } from "vue-router";

const store = useAddapostStore();

</script>
```

If I refresh the log in page I see the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: []: getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
    const pinia = createPinia()
    app.use(pinia)
This will fail in production.
```

Why is this error happening and what am I doing wrong here please?

The problem is with axios I don't have to use(axios) in the main.js file. Wonder why some people add it to the main.js file and it works but for me it doesn't.

But now I have another problem. I got pinia working and it says the store is installed and I see the user id when I am logged in. As soon as I refresh the data is lost and the user id becomes 0. Why is the store not keeping my data?

Comment: along with the answer already given, there is no need to import the actual store or include it in a `use(store)` in main.js for pinia.

Comment: Sorry not getting you. In all docs and videos I watched it says I must use it in main.js and import it in the component I want to use it. so how then am I supposed to use it please?

Comment: I'm referencing this line in your main.js: `import { store } from "./store";`  Check the [official documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/getting-started.html#installation).  It's not necessary.  You only need the `createPinia` import and `use(pinia)`

Answer (score 1):

You can’t pass multiple plugins to a single `app.use()` method.
Instead, you have to chain them - one plugin each:

```js
app.use(…).use(…)
```

Comment: Yes then I get this error: Uncaught InternalError: too much recursion